# Call a protected method (constructor) via RTTI

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

am using XE-2.

Is it possible to invoke a protected method (constructor) using RTTI?

I searched the web but did not find any conclusive answer. I understand that prior to XE only published methods/properties were available. I do have write access to private fields, so I was expecting to be able to invoke protected methods.

The following code works as long as the constructor is public.

```
function GetDefaultConstructor(aRttiType: TRttiType): TRttiMethod;
var
   Method: TRttiMethod;
begin
   for Method in aRttiType.GetMethods('Create') do
   begin
      if (Method.IsConstructor) and (length(Method.GetParameters) = 0) and (Method.Parent = aRttiType) then
         Exit(Method);
   end;
   Result := nil;
end;
```

Comment: Extended RTTI was introduced in D2010, not XE.

Comment: If protected methods are included in RTTI then you'll be able to call it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2505373/65863

Comment: In XE2 (did not check other versions), neither `TRttiType.GetMethods()` nor `TRttiType.GetDeclaredMethods()` will include *protected* methods/constructors.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan how do I include protected methods in ExtendedRtti?

Comment: @santiagoIT I've added an answer to explain that

Comment: @Remy Not so. Protected methods are available in XE2, and indeed all extended RTTI versions, if you ask for them to be included in the linked RTTI info.

Comment: @santiagoIT - is it strictly necessary to invoke the constructor via RTTI, or are you assuming that this is necessary because the constructor is protected ?  If the latter then you may be able to simplify your problem by using a different technique altogether, not involving RTTI (and thereby avoiding the RTTI bloat !).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

RTTI information increases the size of executable files. Because of this the designers provided a means for the developer to specify how much RTTI information is to be linked to the executable.

By default, no RTTI for protected methods is linked. So you have to specify that you want this RTTI to be added. For example, this program

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.TypInfo, System.Rtti;

type
  TMyClass = class
  protected
    constructor Create;
  end;

constructor TMyClass.Create;
begin
end;

var
  ctx: TRttiContext;
  method: TRttiMethod;

begin
  for method in ctx.GetType(TMyClass).GetMethods do
    if method.Visibility=mvProtected then
      Writeln(method.Name);
end.
```

produces no output. However, this program

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.TypInfo, System.Rtti;

type
  {$RTTI EXPLICIT METHODS([vcProtected])}
  TMyClass = class
  protected
    constructor Create;
  end;

constructor TMyClass.Create;
begin
end;

var
  ctx: TRttiContext;
  method: TRttiMethod;

begin
  for method in ctx.GetType(TMyClass).GetMethods do
    if method.Visibility=mvProtected then
      Writeln(method.Name);
end.
```

outputs

```
Create
```

For more information, refer to these documentation topics:

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/RTTI_directive_%28Delphi%29
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Working_with_RTTI_Index

Answer (score 11):

By the default the RTTI doesn't include info about the protected methods or constructors, However you can use [`RTTI EXPLICIT`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/RTTI_directive_%28Delphi%29) Directive to include RTTI info of protected methods like so.

```
  {$RTTI EXPLICIT METHODS([vcPrivate, vcProtected, vcPublic, vcPublished])}
  TFoo= class
  protected
    constructor Create;
  end;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you do not need RTTI and were simply under the impression that this was the only way to call a **protected** method from anywhere other than within a sub-class, then there may another way to achieve what you want.

The **protected** visibility specifier in Delphi has a useful idiosyncracy:  As well as limiting visibility to sub-classes, **protected** members are also visible to other classes *declared in the same unit as those sub-classes*.  This enables a unit to gain access to the protected members of any arbitrary class by creating a sub-class and using that sub-class rather than the original.  You can even use the sub-class to type-cast a reference to an instance that is a sub-class of the required base class incorporating the required protected methods, irrespective of the actual class of the object involved.

**Strictly Speaking**

This however does **NOT** apply if the methods are declared as **strict protected**.  But as long as the methods are only **protected**, then you can use the technique.

**By Way of Example**

For example, The **DestroyWindowHandle** method of a VCL **TWinControl** is a **protected** method.  But using this technique you can call this directly on any instance of a **TWinControl**, regardless of it's actual class.  As a silly demonstration of this, consider a button that for some crazy reason wanted to directly destroy it's own underlying HWND when clicked, without destroying the button itself:

```
type
  TWinControlEx = class(TWinControl);


procedure TMyForm.MyButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TWinControlEx(Sender).DestroyWindowHandle;  // button window is destroyed but the button itself remains!
end;
```

This allows you access to protected methods on objects, but what about constructors, which are members of classes rather than objects ?

Well, the same principle applies.  You can create a sub-class directly of the class you wish to instantiate and use that sub-class to instantiate an instance via the protected constructor as you normally would:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

   type
     TFoo = class
     protected
       constructor Create;
     end;

implementation

  constructor TFoo.Create;
  begin
    inherited Create;

    // Foo specific, protected initialisation here....
  end;

end.
```

And then in some other unit...

```
unit Unit1;

  ..

implementation

  uses
    Unit2;

  type
    TFooEx = class(TFoo);


  procedure TMyForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  var
    foo: TFoo;
  begin
    foo := TFooEx.Create;  // << the protected constructor!
  end;
```

The caveat in this case however is that the **foo** instance is actually an instance of **TFooEx** and not **TFoo**.  This may or may not be a problem in your case.  A prime consideration is that any code that includes tests such as:

```
if foo is TFoo then
```

Will still work entirely as expected.  However, more specific tests such as:

```
if foo.ClassType = TFoo then
```

Will not (since *foo.ClassType* = **TFooEx**, not **TFoo**).

Since the methods you are attempting to obtain access to are **protected**, your sub-class does not have to extend *directly* from the class that introduces the methods, but can extend any class that *derives from* that class.  So, for example if the actual class you needed to instantiate is itself some sub-class of the (example) **TFoo** then you simply ensure that your class derives from that one, not the base:

```
// unit2

     TFoo = class
     protected
       constructor Create; virtual;
     end;

     TBar = class(TFoo)
     protected
       constructor Create; override;
     end;
```

And then in another unit...

```
TFooEx = class(TBar);


procedure ....;
var
  foo: TFoo;
begin
  foo := TFooEx.Create;  // << creates a TBar using protected TBar constructor
end;
```

**Advantages**

One advantage of this over an RTTI based approach is that it avoids the need to have all that RTTI embedded in your application.

Another advantage is that if the signatures of the protected methods that you call in this way are changed then the code will simply not compile, rather than only failing at runtime.  It also means you get assistance from code completion and insight when composing your constructor call, reducing the chance of making an error in the number or type of parameters.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I was aware of it already though. In this particular case I need to use RTTI.